# Calling a javascript select change from c#

Tags: asp.net

I have javascript function when a control value is changed i am firing a javascript now i wanted to do from c# code.When a value to a control is assigned i wanted it to fire the javascript .Please Help !!.

```
function AddSelectedUser(sender, eventArgs) {
    var dataItem = eventArgs.get_DataItem();

    if (dataItem != null) {
        // get the selected values
        var subscribedUserId = parseInt(eventArgs.get_Value());
        var subscribedUserText = eventArgs.get_Text();
        var recipientType = dataItem.get_attributes().getAttribute("RecipientType");

        //Check if the selected user or group already exists in the selected list
        var isExisting = false;
        var JSONString = $get(hdnSelectedUsersJsonId).value;
        var selectedUserColl = new Array();
        if (JSONString != "") {
            selectedUserColl = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(JSONString);
        }

        for (j = 0; j < selectedUserColl.length; j++) {
            if (selectedUserColl[j].DisplayID == subscribedUserId && selectedUserColl[j].RecipientType == recipientType) {
                isExisting = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isExisting == false) {
            //Add the selected user or group.
            var emptyRecipient = new Object();
            emptyRecipient.DisplayID = subscribedUserId;
            emptyRecipient.DisplayName = subscribedUserText;
            emptyRecipient.RecipientType = recipientType;

            selectedUserColl.push(emptyRecipient);
            $get(hdnSelectedUsersJsonId).value = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(selectedUserColl);
            ConstructTable(false);
        }

        sender.resetData();
        var divScroll = $get('selectedUsersDiv');
        divScroll.scrollTop = divScroll.scrollHeight;
    }
}

<tele:autocomplete runat="server" pickervisible="false" id="SubscribedUsers" height="100px"
                                            width="250px" dropdownwidth="248px" cssclass="susbscribedUser" pickertooltip="Select Users or Notification Groups"
                                            providertype="InstantNotificationUsersProvider" matchingtype="Contains" controlbehavior="RestrictedToDropdown"
                                            onclientsidecomponentchanged="AddSelectedUser" AutoPostBack="true"  />
```

Comment: You do know C# and javascript run in entirely different places, don't you?  Explain **exactly** what you're trying to do, because at the moment you're just showing a lack of basic ASP.NET understanding

Comment: hey when i select a text its firing a javscript function called addselecteduser. now my requirement got changed i am passing a value through query string and i am assigning the value to the control ,at that time i want it to fire the event again

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to call this function from c# then use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript() method.

It's easy just read this method properly and call you function.